# Unable to run SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using MySql and I have configured conf\property file.
When I'm trying to start SonarQube in command prompt, it's not getting started. Can any one help me in finding out error?

```
C:\Users\sxyz\Desktop\sonarqube-4.3.1\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When I typed  localhost:9000 in browser url, the SonarQube home page is not displaying

Comment: First, please take the time to write your question in a good English, because it's hard to read them otherwise. Second, you should update your question to add a copy of the error that you will find in "logs/sonar.log" file - otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the conf/sonar.properties? Could you post it?
Which db are you using? Did you create the db?

You can get it from here: [sonar.properties](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-application/src/main/assembly/conf/sonar.properties)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're doing the same project, please make sure you use the right version, we need to use 3.7.4.